# Is XXTEA a good encryption algorithm for a PIC microcontroller?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, embedded, xxtea

I need a good encrypt algorithm for a PIC microcontroller. After some googling, it seems XXTEA is the only option, however, ["XXTEA is vulnerable to a chosen-plaintext attack requiring 2^59 queries and negligible work"](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/254.pdf).

I am not good at cryptography, so I would like to ask: how accurate is the above statement? Could I use XXTEA in a commercial security application? If no, is there any available algorithm I could use for my embedded system?

Comment: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/570/types-of-cryptography-for-a-4-8-bit-microcontroller has a high-level discussion. How much memory do you have?

Comment: @GameScripting: I use 18F13K50 so it has limited memory. @ Gilles: thanks, I have 512KB RAM, program memory depends on other feature but I guess I have 2-3 KB

Answer (score 12):

You cannot know what makes an encryption algorithm secure. *Nobody* knows what makes an encryption algorithm secure. The best we have are "algorithms which have sustained heavy scrutiny from hundreds of cryptographers during many years, and are still relatively unscathed". This is the case for [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard), not for [XXTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA). We may note that the attack on XXTEA is still very expensive, on the verge of the feasible and probably not applicable to most "commercial" situations, but still, this algorithm has been demonstrated flaky. As such, if you value your security, don't get creative with your crypto; use well-vetted standards.

*Why* would you want to use XXTEA ? What does it do for you, that AES does not ? You may want to have a look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13275/smallest-aes-implementation-for-microcontrollers) for some pointers to implementations of AES for some PIC microcontrollers.

(The main design criterion of TEA and its derivatives like XXTEA was to have compact *source code*, so that it could be learned by heart and typed again on a computer. This does not immediately translates to compactness of *compiled code*. (X*)TEA algorithms tend to be slow and to rely on 32-bit operations which are ill-fitting for small microcontrollers.)

Comment: Great answer!  One nit-pick is that your first two sentences should really say, "You cannot know _if_ an encryption algorithm secure. Nobody knows _if a particular algorithm is_ secure."  A secure algorithm is one in which it is computationally unfeasible to break. Also, a cipher with a key the same length of the plain-text is unbreakable (just not practical).  If there is any repetition in the key then the cipher is breakable, but not necessarily computationally feasible.

Comment: thanks Thomas, I will look at those AES. Maybe I need to change IC for AES

Answer (score 0):

One would look for other encryption methods like XXTEA if they want block size to be lesser than 128 bits. Because you may have communication medium with very low bandwidth like powerline communication in noisy environment. There are useful data transmission of only few bytes like 4 or 5 bytes of payload. In this condition, if AES is used, then the block size becomes 16 bytes and creates lot of overhead on the bandwidth available.
In case of XXTEA the block size is only 64 bits (8 bytes) so creates less overhead.